# Jedit git plugin usage

Tags: plugins, gitlab, jedit

I have installed the Git Plugin for JEdit but dont see how to make it work.
I currently use the SVN Plugin and have no issues with this but work is asking for a change to gitlab.

Where do I setup the access to the gitlab repository and what is it expecting as a URL or SSH URI

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can clone that GitLab repo in command line, you are able to use the same url in the [JEdit Git plugin](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?GitPlugin).

So check first you can clone the repo manually:

```
git clone https://url/to/your/gitlab/server/user/repo
```

If that works, report that url in JEdit.

Looking at the sources of the [JEdit Git plugin 0.7.1](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/jedit-plugins/GitPlugin-0.7.1.zip), I do see the:

- "modified" icon is yellow: [image: modified]
- "added" icon is blue: [image: added]
- any other tracked file should be "unmodified", that is green: [image: unmodified]

Note/update April 2017: I cannot make that plugin work on Windows with the latest jdk 8 and Git for Windows 2.12.2.

I see:

```
16:02:37 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [debug] EditBus: PluginUpdate[what=ACTIVATED,exit=false,version=0.7.1,source=C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Roaming\jEdit\jars\GitPlugin.jar,class=git.GitPlugin]
16:03:32 [jEdit Worker #1] [debug] GitSubmoduleImporter: Running git ls-files in C:\Users\vonc\data\git\seec
16:03:43 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [debug] ActionSet: Loading actions from jeditresource:/GitPlugin.jar!/actions.xml
```

But when activating the Commit dialog box, the list is empty, and clicking on it triggers:

```
16:04:02 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
16:04:02 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0:  at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:734)
16:04:02 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0:  at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
16:04:02 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0:  at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.elementAt(DefaultListModel.java:266)
16:04:02 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0:  at git.action.CommitAction$CommitDialog.toggle(CommitAction.java:374)
16:04:02 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0:  at git.action.CommitAction$CommitDialog.mouseClicked(CommitAction.java:363)
16:04:02 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0:  at git.action.CommitAction$CommitDialog.access$200(CommitAction.java:167)
16:04:02 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0:  at git.action.CommitAction$CommitDialog$3.mouseClicked(CommitAction.java:285)
```

What concerns me is [`GitPlugin\git\command\OpenFileList.java`](https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/GitPlugin/ci/master/tree/git/command/OpenFileList.java#l89) which includes

```
    if (line.startsWith("# Changed but not updated:") ||
        line.startsWith("# Changes not staged for commit:")) {
        skip = 2;
        target = modified;
    }
```

Well... my prompt on Windows does not start with '#', so changes of detecting staged files become slim.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP. @VonC, can you be more specific on where should I report my url in jEdit? Thanks. btw. I can modify any files, but in "commit" it still see no modified files.

Comment: @pisoir Modifying files is not enough for "commit" to see them as to be committed. You need to add those files to the index first (equivalent of `git add`)

Comment: @pisoir of course, make sure the files open in JEdit  are part of a git repo (do a `git status` in the parent folder of the files you have changed, for instance)

Comment: Yes, I am modifying files which are already in the index. They are in the git folder and I see them on server. Also git blame in jEdit shows on the modified lines "Not Committed Yet". However, when I do "commit changes" there are no Files to commit.

Comment: @pisoir Can you check with command line? Does git status list those same modified files as "ready to be committed" (and not as "modified, not yet staged")?

Comment: Yes, it says "Changes to be committed:" This:
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   e4z/get_orders.php

Comment: I modified the file "get_orders.php" and in jEdit in ProjectViewer in shows a yellow icon (I assume meaning that it was modified), but still if I go to Plugins->Git Plugin->Commit changes, then there are no files shown as modified.

Comment: @pisoir yes, but modified does not mean to be committed. I have edited the answer to show the relevant icons.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Now I understand your first comment:). But how can I add it to the index through jEdit? (it is added through git add already, so I guess I have to let jEdit know somehow). I really just want modify files in jEdit, then click on commit in jEdit and it will be updated on server. If I have to do git add, git commit in a separate window then jEdit looses all the charm for me.

Comment: @pisoir Yes, I am investigating that. I have edited the answer with what I have found so far.